# valid() function is coming true asp.net jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have added below code for formValidation on my page

```
 $(function () {
 $('#<%=Page.Form.ClientID%>').formValidation({
                framework: 'bootstrap',
                icon: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },

                // This option will not ignore invisible fields which belong to inactive panels
                excluded: ':disabled',

                fields: {
                    mgrbonus: {
                        validators: {

                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/,
                                message: '<%=Resources.LocalizedText.ManagerBonusAmountTwodecimalsSepbyDecimal%>'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    txtSalaryOption: {
                        validators: {

                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/,
                                message: '<%=Resources.LocalizedText.SalaryAmountTwodecimalsSepbyDecimal%>'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

On button click , I am calling a below function:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="lastTab();">Lukk</button>--%>



function lastTab() {


        if ( $('#<%=Page.Form.ClientID%>').valid()) == true) {
            $('.nav-layout-sidebar a:last').tab('show')
        }


    }
```

But if validation is fail for some TextBox, still its passing to next tab.Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
 $('#<%=Page.Form.ClientID%>').validate(); 
 if ( $('#<%=Page.Form.ClientID%>').valid()) == true) {
            $('.nav-layout-sidebar a:last').tab('show')
        }
```